# How to merge Github private repo main branch code to public repo main branch

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, cicd

Suppose I Have Two Github Repo. One is Private repo whose name is **'PrivateExample'** and another is Public Repo whose name is **'PublicExample'**. When a pull request ***merges*** in the **'PrivateExample'**  private repo main branch, it also pushes this latest main branch code into the **'PublicExample'** public repo main branch. Is it possible to the GitHub actions for this criteria requirement...

```
name: Sync to Public Repo

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: johndoe/PublicExample
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT_FOR_SYNC }}

      - name: Set up Git
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "johndoe@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "johndoe"

      - name: Merge and push to public repo
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged
        run: |
          git remote add public-repo https://github.com/johndoe/PublicExample.git
          git fetch public-repo
          git checkout main
          git merge public-repo/main --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merge changes from PrivateExample" || true
          git remote set-url origin https://johndoe:${{ secrets.PAT_FOR_SYNC }}@github.com/johndoe/PublicExample.git
          git push origin main
```

I try this above code. It works fine but no code merge **PrivateExample** repo main branch to **PublicExample** public repo main branch.